# SwiftUI TabView: .tabItem with custom font does not work

Tags: swiftui, tvos13

Is anybody familiar with the issue that the tabItem of a SwiftUI TabView, doesn't apply custom fonts? At least not for tvOS13.

For the TabView itself a custom font is easily applied, but when trying to customise the font for the actual .tabItem, it doesn't do anything, but it also doesn't return any errors.

First I tried setting a `let`:

```
let fontCustom = Font.custom("Awesome Font Name", size: 25)
```

Then creating the `TabView`:

```
Text("Kanalen")
    .font(fontCustom)
...
```

Works, but then adding a TabItem to that view the same way doesn't:

```
...
.tabItem {
    HStack {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "icon.pdf")!)
        Text("Awesome Item")
            .font(Font.custom("Cera-Regular", size: 16))            
    }
}
...
```

Or like this:

```
.tabItem {
    HStack {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "icon.pdf")!)
        Text("Awesome Item")
            .font(Font.custom("Awesome Font Name", size: 16))            
    }
}
```

Anybody has a clue as to why this is not working, and does this mean I'll need to create a custom tabItem View completely?

Thanks all!

Comment: I Have the same problem too.

Answer (score 15):

This seems to do the trick, but uses the underlying UIKIt controls. Hope Apple implements this into swiftui soon.

`init() {
 UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.init(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 15)! ], for: .normal)
}`

Comment: This is not correct. you are changing appearance globally. It may cause problem in other views.

Comment: It's a good compromise for apps that only have one tab bar until SwiftUI adds native support for custom font in `TabView`.